Linux Assembler bss data is overlapping?
I have the following 2 modules that have overlapping address's
You can see that n_Companies extends into savedRegisters causing untold problems.
Can anyone shed some light on this for me ?
MODULE=pV308.ASM
    section .bss
        ALIGN 8                                     ; Align stuff
        n_Companies resq 13                         ; Reserve the memory

MODULE=COMMON.LIB
    section .bss
        ALIGN 8                                     ; Align stuff
        savedRegisters times 384 resq 1             ; Reserve the memory

OBJDUMP -x
0000000000ce2271 l     O .bss   0000000000000001      n_Companies

    13*8=104 0x68
    ce2271+68=CE22D9

0000000000ce22cc g       .bss   0000000000000000      savedRegisters


Perhaps the object for pV308.asm is out of data? n_Companies is not even aligned to 8 bytes.

Sorry, I don't understand that response. What does "out of data" mean. Why is n_Companies not aligned ?

Sorry, that should have been "out of date," i.e. your object corresponds to an older version of the source code and had not been rebuilt.

They have been rebuilt many times with my trying to figure this out. Using ddd/gdb I have watched saveRegisters be updated and see the values being written in to n_Companies

Do you use a custom linker script or something?  I think to go ahead we need a [mcve] such that others can reproduce your problem.

Neighter of the symbols aren't even aligned to the requested alignment. Firstly you need to dig into what is responsible for this - assembler or linker. Dump relevant object files before archival and linkage and see if they contain sane offsets and sizes.

No custom script. And this has only reared its head as the system became more complicated so a "minimal reproducible example"  is a complicated milti language example.

I had hoped asking here was digging into what is responsible. I had thought that the ojdump example ruled out the linker ??

It is not obvious which file did you objdumped, but it looks like final executable. So you know something is wrong but do you know if that is linker working off bad data, or linker doing something bad? See what's happening in pV308.o. How is .bss defined in there? What n_Companies symbol looks like?

Andrey.. I appreciate you effort but all you suggest has been done... ,"is the linker working off bad data" Well its working with compiled/assembled files that have been working up until now. "Linker doing something bad" I don't know it looks like it. "See whats happening in pV308.o" I know what's happening in there because I wrote it. "How is .bss defined" It is defined as per my original post. "What n_Companies look like" Looks like my original post.

@rogertunnicliffe I am unable to diagnose your problem from the information you have provided.  If you don't think you can supply additional details, I don't think I'll be able to solve your problem.

As fuz said in his initial comment, the symbols are not even aligned. It's extremely suspicious that you did not build the binary from the source given or you have removed relevant parts of the code. ALIGN 8 should make the address aligned to 8 bytes but neither  ce2271 nor ce22cc is aligned. Note that you should be using ALIGNB in .bss but according to my tests ALIGN also works with a warning. Also the size of n_Companies is 1 which might indicate that you are not looking at the correct symbol. It might exist in another module as well and not overlap.

@rogertunnicliffe do you want some help or not? "It worked before" - not a proof of correctness. "Looks like it" - you ought to prove if it is or not. "I wrote it" - did you wrote nasm as well? "It is defined as per my original post" - no it isn't!!! You shown assembly. You didn't check what nasm did with it. Or failed to mention it. objdump says n_Companies is 1-aligned 1-byte area. Here's the thing: 99.99% your tools work fine, and it is your error somewhere. You are either assembling wrong thing, or linking wrong thing. So check obj file, recheck linker cmdline, check linker (output) map.

So if anyone else looks it this thread know that I used a work-around not a solution (rather unsatisfying). There was a 2 qword overlap between n_Companies & savedRegister and as people noted the items were not aligned as you would expect them to be. I am not convinced that I could have done anything to cause this and so have assumed that there is nothing I can do to fix it. The work-around is to increase the size of n_Companies by 2 qwords which meant savedRegsiters is overwriting an area that I do not use. Whatya gonna do eh !

@rogertunnicliffe Something must have caused this.  But as you refuse to provide additional information or a [mcve], it's not possible for any of us to find out what exactly that is.

@fuz I think this is a misrepresentation. I do not "refuse" to provide information. 1st of all you need to be proficient in nasm and masm. You would need to learn and understand "languageone" in both linux and windows versions. In addition you need to know Pascal and Lazarus and then know how it all hangs together.  My hope with the post was that someone had come across this problem previously and been able to share their thoughts. I had no expectation that someone could replicate the problem as it is a mature system that I take responsibility for.

@rogertunnicliffe Okay.  Let me summarise what we know about your situation: somehow, the size and alignment of some bss reservations changes between source and final binary.  You refuse to investigate if this happens in the object files or only after linking.  You say that this happened spontaneously and refuse to investigate if any change in your code might have caused this. You refuse to provide a [mcve] or take any step towards isolating the cause. You refuse to give further details about you build system or tools used besides this being for nasm. How do you expect anybody to solve this?

Your comment sounds a lot like you expect someone to magically be able to diagnose your exact issue from the minimal details you have provided.  While that would be great of course, it's very unlikely.  So without some debugging effort and assistance in providing the relevant details or a [mcve] on your part, it is very unlikely that a solution will obtain.

Did you actually read anything I wrote. What do you think I've been doing for the last 3 days. I'll tell you what I "refuse" to do and that's engage any further with someone like yourself.

OK, so finally found this error and wanted to post for anyone else that runs into the same thing (Although they might not unless they are an idiot like me !!!). Deep in the bowels of a macro copy file I had coded 'inc qword[_STOP]' {a debugging mechanism}. You would be foolish to include this in the .bss section (or the .data section)  cuz it's really going to mess up NASM.  Tough one to find this error but let's just say -> me 0 nasm 1

Dare say, how exactly did you figure it out? Just so mere mortals like me know how to approach something like that in the future. What was your process of debugging this?

I guess it was just 3 days of digging and slowly culling bits of the program until I could get rid of the problem and then adding bits back untill the problem recurred. As usual it was not anything that I had expected and totally my own fault. I am still confused in the way that it manifested but I am now in a position that when someone posts a similar problem that I can say "Yeah dude, happened to me, try checking that you haven't got any stray code in .bss or .data.   Thanks for your interest Andrey.
